# ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions, this is the error which I'm getting in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO customer_data
  (cus_id, cust_name, age, city, salary)
VALUES
  (1, 'Sam', 'Delhi',9000),
  (2, 'ROhit', 'Banglore', 5000),
  (3, 'Rahul', 'Mumbai', 12000),
  (4, 'Sunny', 'Odisha',15000);
```

This is my Code

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query should contain same number of columns as same number of values
you column count in this

```
INSERT INTO customer_data (**cus_id**, **cust_name**, **age**, **city**, **salary**)
```

part of query is 5 whereas value count is 4 in this part

```
VALUES (**1**, **'Sam'**, **'Delhi'**,**9000**) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the values part is missing the *age* value